# How to recover previous value this (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

is possible to recover somewhat the previous value associated with `this`?

I am creating a dynamic menu and for me is necessary ... unfortunately the code is too long and I can not bring it back here or on jsfiddle, but I created a simple example that you understand what I mean:

```
<div id="block-system-main-menu">
 <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Mappe</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Vulc</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Equa</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

And here js code:

```
$('#block-system-main-menu').on('click', 'li', function () {


if ($(this).children('a').text() != cliccato) {

    $(this).append('<span> clicked</span>');
    alert('not equal');


} else if ($(this).children('a').text() == cliccato) {
    $(this).find('span').remove();
    alert('equal');

}
//
var cliccato = $(this).children('a').text();

});
```

Here the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ve1cd5vx/

practically the first time clicking on a link I added the span, but when I click again on the same link does not remove the span ...

so doesn't work the `else if` of js code... because the variable `cliccato` is undefined, but if there is a way to recover the previous value of `this`, it would be all resolved..

(other solutions, which have already proven how to create variables that change the value based on the number of clicks in my case would only greatly extend the code)

Thanks and sorry for my english

Comment: In your jsfiddle `cliccato` is `undefined` so the `text` value of any clicked link will always be different from it (and the second branch won't be executed).
Try to use a class to (`.js-clicked` ?) when a click happen, then just check the existence of such class as criteria in the `if`.

Comment: Another small point about the `if/else` block is that you do not need a second `if`, a simple else is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is store the previous element that was clicked. Since you're doing that inside your function, `var cliccato` is only available in that function, and it doesn't exist outside (scoping).

Instead, you can make `cliccato` a global variable, so you can read and update the value inside your function.

EDIT: as @davcs86 pointed out, there's also the issue of not adding a second `<span>`, so I added a line to remove any spans before adding the new one to address that.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8rfpmts0/1/

```
var cliccato = null; // now declared OUTSIDE the function
$('#block-system-main-menu').on('click', 'li', function () {


    if ($(this).children('a').text() != cliccato) {
        $(this).find('span').remove(); // Don't add extra spans
        $(this).append('<span> clicked</span>');
        alert('not equal');


    } else if ($(this).children('a').text() == cliccato) {
        $(this).find('span').remove();
        alert('equal');

    }
    //
    cliccato = $(this).children('a').text();

});
```

Comment: This doesn't satisfy with "the first time clicking on a link I added the span, but when I click again on the same link does not remove the span ..." Your solution produces multiple "clicked" span in the same LI element since you're storing only the last clicked LI in cliccato variable. Try clicking in all LI elements in descending order multiple times and you get this http://i.imgur.com/p1akiec.png

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the jQuery selectors, with something like this

```
$('#block-system-main-menu').on('click', 'li', function () {
    if (!$(this).is(".wasclicked")) {
        $(this).append('<span> clicked</span>');
        $(this).addClass("wasclicked");
    } else {
        $(this).find('span').remove();
        $(this).removeClass("wasclicked");
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ve1cd5vx/1/)

**UPDATE**

Also you can use an IIFE,

```
var cliccato = false; // now declared OUTSIDE the function
$('#block-system-main-menu').on('click', 'li', (function (thisCliccato) {
    return function () {
        if (!thisCliccato) {
            $(this).append('<span> clicked</span>');
        } else {
            $(this).find('span').remove();
        }
        thisCliccato = !thisCliccato;
    }
})(cliccato));
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ve1cd5vx/3/)